# Updating a single field in object Javascript

Tags: javascript, object

I need to change state of specific fields in `problems` object:

```
  const [problems, setProblems] = useState({
    first_name: false,
    last_name: false,
    city: false,
    email: false,
    password: false,
  });
```

I tried something like this below, but it updates for me just the last value of error `Object.keys(error.response.data)` list:

```
.catch((error) => {
        Object.keys(error.response.data).map((err) => {
          setProblems({ ...problems, [err]: true });
        });
      });
```

error is an object that has keys that have the same names as keys in `problems` object. How can I do this correctly that all fields will be updated?

Answer (score 4):

It only updates the state with the *last* state value because of *closure* over the state.

State is **constant** within a particular render of a component; in order to see the updated state, component has to **re-render**.

Since you are calling `setProblems()` multiple times within the same render:

```
setProblems({ ...problems, [err]: true });
```

`problems` in the above statement refers to the *same* state that was in-effect when `Object.keys(...).map(...)` was called. In short, you are *spreading* the *same* state each time `setProblems` is called.

#### Solution

What you need to do is:

1. First create the object that you want to save in the state

   ```
   const newState = { ...problems };

   Object.keys(error.response.data)
         .forEach((err) => newState[err] = true);
   ```
2. Call the state setter function

   ```
   setProblems(newState);
   ```

Comment: Yes that's it! Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
.catch((error) => {
    const newProblems = {...problems};

    Object.keys(error.response.data).forEach((err) => {
        newProblems[err] = true;
    });

    setProblems(newProblems);
});
```

I have not actually tested your original code, but what I am guessing is that since `setState`'s setter is not synchronous, when you call it in a loop you are only applying the last call.